# No encoder has been configured for account with fosUserBundle symfony2.1

Tags: submit, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle, encoder

I have this error when I submit the connexion form (I use FOSUserBundle latest version) :

```
No encoder has been configured for account "MyApp\UtilisateurBundle\Entity\Utilisateur
```

here is my entity :

```
    <?php
namespace MyApp\UtilisateurBundle\Entity;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Utilisateur extends BaseUser
{
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
    * @ORM\generatedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

and here is my app/config/security.yml :

```
imports:
- { resource: "@MyAppFilmothequeBundle/Resources/config/security.yml" }
```

and here is my src/MyApp/FilmothequeBundle/Ressources/config/security.yml :

```
security:
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern:      .*
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            login_path:     /myapp/login
            use_forward:    false
            check_path:     /myapp/login_check
            failure_path:   null
            default_target_path: /myapp
        logout:
            path:   /myapp/logout
            target: /myapp
        anonymous:    true
```

I followed this tutorial to doing that : http://j-place.developpez.com/tutoriels/php/ameliorez-vos-applications-developpees-avec-symfony2/#LVI-B-1

How can I achieve this?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try adding this to the security key in security.yml

```
encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
```

so it's

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    providers:
        ...

    firewalls:
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error on [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle).

It helps me (`config/packages/security.yaml`):

```
security:
    encoders:
      App\Entity\User:
        algorithm: bcrypt
```

Answer (score 2):

You need juste add this code in the security.yml

```
    encoders:
        # use your user class name here
        App\Entity\User:
            # Use native password encoder
            # This value auto-selects the best possible hashing algorithm
            # (i.e. Sodium when available).
            algorithm: auto
```

Im use symfony 4.4

Working for me